# Creating a large ListView with custom complex child Views

Tags: android, listview

I have an unusual project that I need to display large sets of questions to the user.  Given the amount of questions that will be shown on the screen and accessible by the user I have opted to using a `ListView`. I tried a `ScrollView`, but it wasn't as efficient as I wanted, and lagged when dynamically adding new sets of questions.

The basic structure will be a `ListView` whose children are custom Views that I have created that have `LinearLayouts` inside that expand and collapse based on a button in each custom view. The `LinearLayouts` will hold the question's widgets, `TextView`s, `Button`s, `EditText`s, etc. In each collapsible view there will be at least 20 widgets. There will be many custom views in the `ListView`. One problem I had was scrolling of the `ListView` when showing that many widgets.  It worked OK when the custom views were collapsed, but when a bunch were expanded it lagged the scroll.

Is there a more efficient way of displaying huge amounts of widgets than enclosing them in a `ListView`? I thought `ListView` might be my best bet because it recycles the Views.

This is a very unusual project, as the questions inside the `ListView` will change dramatically based on certain information entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having this kind of list is better to use the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

It have a better performance but you only draw one item expaned.